# window.outerWidth is 0 in Safari on iOS 10 beta

Tags: javascript, ios, ios9, ios10

Using an iPad with iOS 10 installed, I entered `window.outerWidth` in the browser console and got a value of `0`. OTOH, `window.innerWidth` correctly produced `1024` (landscape mode).

In iOS 9, `window.outerWidth` correctly produced `1024`, so is this just a bug in the iOS 10 beta or is there a subtlety to this property that I'm missing?

Comment: Seems to be happening more than just in the beta. Not sure the reasoning why, but in a pinch, you could use `screen` instead of `window`, but that won't get you results on other browsers. Additionally, you could use `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width`, and that will get you your window's outer width.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is more than just the iOS 10 Beta, but I doubt it is a priority for Apple Devs to fix as iOS devices don't really have an external frame on the sides of their browser window, so `window.innerWidth` is the same as `window.outerWidth`.

To see this working in a different context, you can pop open the inspector in your browser and emulate a smaller device. The inner width will be equal to the page width, while the outer width will be equal to the full width of the open browser.

If you still need to use outerWidth, what you can do as an alternative is either check the screen width using:

`let mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1025px)" );`

`mq.matches` will evaluate to `true` if you're on a desktop, and you can then use `outerWidth` for desktop and `innerWidth` for mobile. Or you could just make an alternative function to do it for you like this:

```
let screenWidth = () => {
  const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1025px)" );

  if (mq.matches) {
    return window.outerWidth;
  } else {
    return window.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

Note that `1025px` is 1 more pixel wide than an iPad Air 2 in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery in your project, you can use `$(window).outerWidth()` and `$(window).outerHeight()`. It's a workaround that works as expected in all devices.