# HTML5 Canvas + JS Not Working on IOS/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I've implemented a canvas element with a javascript particle effect. The effect is working on every browser but IOS/Safari. I've done a bit of research and IOS/Safari supports HTML5/Canvas: [According to Browser Support Charts for HTML5/Canvas](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas)

```js
$(function() {
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth * .9,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    MAX_PARTICLES = 100,
    DRAW_INTERVAL = 60,
    canvas = document.querySelector('#pixies'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    gradient = null,
    pixies = new Array();

  function setDimensions() { 
    WIDTH = window.outerWidth;
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = WIDTH; 
    canvas.height = HEIGHT; 
  }

  setDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', setDimensions);

  function Circle() {
    this.settings = {ttl:8000, xmax:5, ymax:2, rmax:10, rt:1, xdef:960, ydef:540, xdrift:4, ydrift: 4, random:true, blink:true};

    this.reset = function() {
      this.x = (this.settings.random ? WIDTH*Math.random() : this.settings.xdef);
      this.y = (this.settings.random ? HEIGHT*Math.random() : this.settings.ydef);
      this.r = ((this.settings.rmax-1)*Math.random()) + 1;
      this.dx = (Math.random()*this.settings.xmax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
      this.dy = (Math.random()*this.settings.ymax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
      this.hl = (this.settings.ttl/DRAW_INTERVAL)*(this.r/this.settings.rmax);
      this.rt = Math.random()*this.hl;
      this.settings.rt = Math.random()+1;
      this.stop = Math.random()*.2+.4;
      this.settings.xdrift *= Math.random() * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
      this.settings.ydrift *= Math.random() * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
    }

    this.fade = function() {
      this.rt += this.settings.rt;
    }

    this.draw = function() {
      if(this.settings.blink && (this.rt <= 0 || this.rt >= this.hl)) {
          this.settings.rt = this.settings.rt*-1;
      } else if(this.rt >= this.hl) {
          this.reset();
      }

      var newo = 1-(this.rt/this.hl);
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      context.closePath();

      var cr = this.r*newo;
      gradient = context.createRadialGradient(this.x, this.y, 0, this.x, this.y, (cr <= 0 ? 1 : cr));
      gradient.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,'+newo+')');
      gradient.addColorStop(this.stop, 'rgba(255,255,255,'+(newo*.6)+')');
      gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');
      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fill();
    }

    this.move = function() {
      this.x += (this.rt/this.hl)*this.dx;
      this.y += (this.rt/this.hl)*this.dy;
      if(this.x > WIDTH || this.x < 0) this.dx *= -1;
      if(this.y > HEIGHT || this.y < 0) this.dy *= -1;
    }

    this.getX = function() { return this.x; }
    this.getY = function() { return this.y; }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < MAX_PARTICLES; i++) {
    pixies.push(new Circle());
    pixies[i].reset();
  }

  function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for(var i = 0; i < pixies.length; i++) {
      pixies[i].fade();
      pixies[i].move();
      pixies[i].draw();
    }
  }

  setInterval(draw, DRAW_INTERVAL);
});
```

```css
#particles {
  position: absolute;
  background: navy;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="particles">
   <canvas id="pixies"></canvas>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working in IOS/Safari? The actual site in question is this one: [www.pjmaskslive.com](http://www.pjmaskslive.com)

Comment: An actual look at the developer console might help. Any errors? Also,
 it's generally a good idea to pay attention to the  "known issues" tab on the caniuse site! Sidenote:<troll>Who cares for Safari?</troll>

Comment: There are some rumblings about Safari not playing nicely with Canvas on stackoverflow (ex. it seems like `.bind()` isn't supported). I have no instances of `bind()` anywhere. It's working on desktop-based (OSX) Safari, just not IOS/Safari. Just curious why this is happening.

Comment: The above snippet runs fine for me in Safari on iOS 10.3.2

Comment: @LennartHase: would you mind trying this site on IOS/Safari? http://www.pjmaskslive.com

Comment: @JoelB Okay, not working on the site you linked, however, there are also no errors or warnings in the console, curious...

Comment: @JoelB I think I may have found the issue. If I inspect the canvas element on the iOS site it has a width of 0? Not sure that's intended

Comment: Thanks for investigating for me, I'm not set up to debug IOS at the moment. Ok, that's extremely good info, the canvas width is being set to 0 for some reason, but only on IOS. **perplexing**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144289/discussion-between-lennart-hase-and-joel-b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the canvas elements width is set 0 on the aforementioned [website](http://www.pjmaskslive.com/). So I would assume that the issue is setting the `WIDTH` variable at the start. This might be due to an ongoing bug with iOS 10 as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416855/window-outerwidth-is-0-in-safari-on-ios-10-beta) question.

An alternative approach might be to use `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width` as an alternative to `window.innerWidth` and/or `window.outerWidth`. `screen.width` could also be used, however, these could also have the same issues as your previous methods.

Seems like a safari issue rather than your code either way!

Comment: I set a fix width, the problem still the same, iphone canvas really doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix I used for my project. the code was more than this but the idea was that I wanted to draw on an office plan as a navigating app for workers and I finished the project and it ran perfectly on Android, but did not run on iOS, so I used the `navigator.platform` method, then set the canvas size based on the platform

```
if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod|MacIntel/.test(navigator.platform)) {
  const maxWidth = 5400; // Maximum width
  canvas.width = Math.min(maxWidth, document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width || window.innerWidth || screen.width);
  const aspectRatio = image.width / image.height;
  canvas.height = canvas.width / aspectRatio;

  document.querySelector('.devicename').innerHTML =
    `${navigator.platform}\s
                width ${canvas.width} height: ${canvas.height}\s 
                image height: ${image.height} image width: ${image.width}\s 
                device height: ${window.innerHeight || screen.height} width : ${window.innerWidth || screen.width}`;
}


ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: so this is the fix i used for my project, the code was more than this but the idea was that i wanted to draw on an office plan as a navigating app for workers and i finished the project and it ran perfectly on android but did not run on ios so i user the navigator.platform method then i set the canvas size based on the platform

Comment: Hi David, welcome to StackOverflow! I tried to clean up your answer, there were some duplicates in the code. I also copied the comment explaining what's up to the answer itself. Please take a look if I didn't mess anything up!